# How to create an MS Access application for laptops with different language settings?

Tags: windows, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Context: I work for a Belgian company located in Brussels. I have Dutch and French speaking colleagues, each with their laptop configured in their mother tongue.

I am creating an Access application that needs to run on all the laptops. The problem is that the ms-access variables (not in vba, but in design view) are not translated. The one I find difficult to circumnavigate is "Form". In Dutch it is "Formulieren" in French it's "Formulaires". Ms Access doesn't recognize that all of them are the same. Is there anything I can do? Or do I need to find an other solution for my Form problems? And if so: any hints?

**Example**:

When clicking on the looking glass, a windows opens with more information regarding this person.

[image]
[image]
The looking glass button is a macro that opens the rapport. The rapport searches for the ID of the person in the parent form, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are only localised in the GUI designer. If you switch to SQL view, you'll see:

```
[Forms].[Package Form] .. etc.
```

You also specify these parameters as explicit parameters where you specify the data type as well.

A note: Your criteria's last part should read:

```
![ResponsiblePerPackage Subform].Form![ResponsibleID]
```

Comment: In SQL it also reads [Formulieren] instead of [Forms]. Plus when I open the form in a Dutch environment, it's fine. When I open it in a French one, the form asks to manually input a ResponsibleID. Why are you suggesting that last part? I'm not very pro in this, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: It seems like you are right, at least with Access 2016. It didn't use to be so, but I must admit that I prefer setting the parameters in code. However, it also seems like if you change it to read `[Forms]` and will stay persistent even when you switch back and forth between GUI and SQL view and make edits in either view. The syntax using `Form` is the recommended; you may get away without it, but it may fail.

Comment: okay, this works. I can just use Forms instead of Formulieren, oef!